# 404 after successfuly war deployment

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I'm newbie to docker , trying conteinerize my non-springboot app.
Given:

> contaier with tomcat image `v 10.0.0-jdk15` ;
> deployed War spring app, compiling version 14;
> webapps folder having both .war and app directory unpacked;
> login into tomcat manager gui shows running app;
> logs files shows no errors - just successful deployment;
> I tried all variants , like `/ , /app, /app/web/ - 404` all the time.

> My controller endpoints start with '/' (greeting)
> Any suggestions?

UPD: Tomcat's sample.war deployed correctly.
I forgot to mention, my db is unattached now since I intend to place it into another container.

Comment: have you verified the port number your docker image is running on?

Comment: Yep, here it is \8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8080